# How to move "n" to the top, "i" to the bottom for this symbol $\prod_{i=1}^n$

Tags: symbols

this command

```
\prod_{i=1}^n
```

could generates this symbol

[image]

How to move "n" to the top, "i" to the bottom, like this

[image]

Comment: `\prod\limits_{i=1}^n`

Comment: How are you setting it in the first place? It must be in so-called text style (`\textstyle`). You can use `\displaystyle \prod_{i=1}^n`.

Comment: @Bernard Thanks a lot! Please move your comments to answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: That's not very useful. Lots of comments and answers already mention it. Thanks anyway!